# Why can't we solve this problem with the Lagrangian $L=m*g*R (1 - Cos[θ[t]]) - m*g*R*Cos[θ[t]]$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

I see this mechanical problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223334/how-to-model-the-movement-of-a-mass-over-a-dome).

[image]

I want to solve this problem with the variational method. The Lagrangian of this system is obtained by subtracting potential energy from kinetic energy.

```
m = 1;
g = 9.8;
R = 1;
EulerEquations[
 m*g*R (1 - Cos[θ[t]]) - m*g*R*Cos[θ[t]], θ[
  t], t](*L=T-V or L=kinetic energy - potential energy*)
```

But the result is $19.6 (\sin  (\theta  [t]))=0$, which has no significance to solve this problem.

I know that by listing the Lagrangian of this system, we can get the correct equation of motion:

```
<< VariationalMethods`
L = 1/2 m (R θ'[t])^2 - m g R Cos[θ[t]];
EulerEquations[L, θ[t], t] // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> R > 0 && m > 0] &
```

But before the object moves along the sphere and does not separate, the kinetic energy of the system $ m g R (1-\cos (\theta (t)))=\frac{1}{2} m \left(R \theta '(t)\right)^2$.

I want to know what mistakes I made in listing the following Lagrangian of this system(`L= m*g*R (1 - Cos[θ[t]]) - m*g*R*Cos[θ[t]]`), and how to use the variational method to solve this problem correctly.

Comment: If you want to solve with the Lagrangian method, you should not use the conservation of energy. If you do so you are essentially imposing that the equation of motion are satisfied, so there is nothing to variate.

Comment: @GCLL Thank you very much. Can you give a theoretical basis for this or an analysis of similar topics (preferably a textbook)?

Comment: You can check out Goldstein’s Classical Mechanics. I think the constraint forces are there in chapter 1